# Herbrand universe, Herbrand Base and Herbrand Model of binary tree (prolog)

Tags: prolog

What is the Herbrand universe, Herbrand Base and Herbrand Model of binary tree:

```
binary_tree(empty). 
binary_tree(tree(Left,Element,Right)) :- 
     binary_tree(Left), 
     binary_tree(Right).
```

Answer (score 8):

The Herbrand universe are the ground terms of a given signature. Many Prolog
systems have a predicate ground/1 which you can use to check whether a term is
actually ground. The definition of ground/1 is that it doesn't contain variables:

```
?- ground(empty).
Yes
?- ground(tree(X,Y,Z)).
No
```

The Herbrand base are the ground prime formulas of a given signature. A
prime formula is a predicate or an equality. You can also use ground/1
to check whether a prime formula is ground:

```
?- ground(a = X).
No
?- ground(a = b).
Yes
?- ground(binary_tree(X)).
No
?- ground(binary_tree(tree(empty,n,empty))).
Yes
```

A Herbrand model is a model where the universe is a Herbrand universe. Viewed
as a diagram a Herbrand model is a subset of a Herbrand base. A theory might
have none, one or many Herbrand models.

Horn Clauses always have a Herbrand model, in particular the full Herbrand model
which is the Herbrand base itself, is always a model. Horn Clauses together with
the Clark Equational Theory also have a unique minimal Herbrand model. Which is
the fixpoint of the Herbrand program operator. Certain properties of the program
operator allow to state that the fixpoint can be reached at stage omega.

But working with Herbrand models is clumsy, since they are not sorted. Many
sorted signatures and corresponding ground models are more handy. For simplicity
and to avoid many sorted logic in the present case we could assume that your
program reads, i.e. that the tree elements are peano numbers:

```
binary_tree(empty). 
binary_tree(tree(Left,Element,Right)) :- 
    binary_tree(Left),
    tree_element(Element), 
    binary_tree(Right).
tree_element(n).
tree_element(s(X)) :-
    tree_element(X).
```

Then your binary tree definition would lead to the following recurrence
relation:

```
T_0 = {}
T_n+1 = {binary_tree(empty)} u {binary_tree(tree(s,e,t)) | 
       binary_tree(s) in T_n, 
       tree_element(e) in T_n, 
       binary_tree(t) in T_n } u 
        {tree_element(n)} u {tree_element(s(e)) |
       tree_element(e) in T_n} u T_n
```

The unique minimal Herbrand model would then be T = union_n T_n which is
the least fixpoint of the above recurrence relation. Looks like
nothing has been said.

Comment: Maybe there is not an Herbrand model, because of singleton Element? I'm unable to enumerate the ground terms...

Comment: Stictly speaking, in first order logic, the universe has to be non-empty. So at least one constant needs to be assumed.

Comment: so, what is the Herbrand Universe here? HU={element} Am I right?

Comment: Unsorted with the signatur empty/0, n/0, s/1, tree/3 we have HU = {empty, n, s(empty), s(n), tree(empty,empty,empty), tree(n,empty,empty), etc..}