# Herbrand universe and Least herbrand Model

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I read the question asked in [Herbrand universe, Herbrand Base and Herbrand Model of binary tree (prolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509350/herbrand-universe-herbrand-base-and-herbrand-model-of-binary-tree-prolog) and the answers given, but I have a slightly different question more like a confirmation and hopefully my confusion will be clarified.

Let P be a program such that we have the following facts and rule:

```
q(a, g(b)).
q(b, g(b)).
q(X, g(X)) :- q(X, g(g(g(X)))).
```

From the above program, the Herbrand Universe

```
Up = {a, b, g(a), g(b), q(a, g(a)), q(a, g(b)), q(b, g(a)), q(b, g(b)), g(g(a)), g(g(b))...e.t.c}
```

Herbrand base:

```
Bp = {q(s, t) | s, t E Up}
```

- Now come to my question(forgive me for my ignorance), i included q(a, g(a)) as an element in my Herbrand Universe but from the fact, it states q(a, g(b)). Does that mean that q(a, g(a)) does not suppose to be there?
- Also since the Herbrand models are subset of the Herbrand base, how do i determine the least Herbrand model by induction?

Note: I have done a lot of research on this, and some parts are well clear to me but still i have this doubt in me thats why i want to seek the communities opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From having the fact `q(a,g(b))` you cannot conclude whether or not `q(a,g(a))` is in the model. You will have to generate the model first.

For determining the model, start with the facts `{q(a,g(b)), q(b,g(b))}` and now try to apply your rules to extend it.  In your case, however, there is no way to match the right-hand side of the rule `q(X,g(X)) :- q(X,g(g(g(X)))).` to above facts. Therefore, you are done.

Now *imagine* the rule

```
q(a,g(Y)) :- q(b,Y).
```

This rule could be used to extend our set. In fact, the instance

```
q(a,g(g(b))) :- q(b,g(b)).
```

is used: If `q(b,g(b))` is present, conclude `q(a,g(g(b)))`. Note that we are using here the rule right-to-left. So we obtain

```
{q(a,g(b)), q(b,g(b)), q(a,g(g(b)))}
```

thereby reaching a fixpoint.

Now take as another example you suggested the rule

```
q(X, g(g(g(X)))) :- q(X, g(X)).
```

Which permits (I will no longer show the instantiated rule) to generate in one step:

```
{q(a,g(b)), q(b,g(b)), q(a,g(g(g(b)))), q(b, g(g(g(b))))}
```

But this is not the end, since, again, the rule can be applied to produce even more! In fact, you have now an infinite model!

```
{g(a,gn+1(b)), g(b, gn+1(b))}
```

---

This right-to-left reading is often very helpful when you are trying to understand recursive rules in Prolog. The top-down reading (left-to-right) is often quite difficult, in particular, since you have to take into account backtracking and general unification.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i think i am getting it. What is the rule changes for instance q(X, g(g(g(X)))) :- q(X, g(X)).? Also is my Herbrand Universe correct?

Comment: @Plaix: The Herbrand Universe is just all possible combinations.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your question:

"Also since the Herbrand models are subset of the Herbrand base, how do i determine the least Herbrand model by induction?"

If you have a set P of horn clauses, the definite program, then you can define 
a program operator:

```
T_P(M) := { H S | S is ground substitution, (H :- B) in P and B S in M }
```

The least model is:

```
inf(P) := intersect { M | M |= P }
```

Please note that not all models of a definite program are fixpoints of the
program operator. For example the full herbrand model is always a model of 
the program P, which shows that definite programs are always consistent, but 
it is not necessarily a fixpoint.

On the other hand each fixpoint of the program operator is a model of the 
definite program. Namely if you have T_P(M) = M, then one can conclude 
M |= P. So that after some further mathematical reasoning(*) one finds that
the least fixpoint is also the least model:

```
lfp(T_P) = inf(P)
```

But we need some further considerations so that we can say that we can determine
the least model by a kind of computation. Namely one easily observes that the
program operator is contiguous, i.e. preserves infinite unions of chains, since
horn clauses do not have forall quantifiers in their body:

```
union_i T_P(M_i) = T_P(union_i M_i)
```

So that again after some further mathematical reasoning(*) one finds that we can 
compute the least fixpoint via iteration, witch can be used for simple 
induction. Every element of the least model has a simple derivation of finite
depth:

```
union_i T_P^i({}) = lpf(T_P)
```

Bye

(*)
Most likely you find further hints on the exact mathematical reasoning 
needed in this book, but unfortunately I can't recall which sections 
are relevant:
Foundations of Logic Programming, John Wylie Lloyd, 1984
http://www.amazon.de/Foundations-Programming-Computation-Artificial-Intelligence/dp/3642968287